# Using meteor, is it possible to build an app with cordova using windows 7 ?

Tags: windows, cordova, meteor

There after, the link which explain how to build an app with meteor and cordova:
[Meteor Cordova Integration in github](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration)

But it seems that it can only be done under linux or iOS. Is it possible to build an app for android under windows 7 ? If it's possible, is there any specific installation to follow? I found that link : [Using phonegap cordova](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/using-phonegap-cordova.html) from the webstorm site. Installing cordova that way will be compatible with meteor development?

Any information about this subject will be appreciated.

Comment: I do believe you can simple package a Meteor app for android with meteors built in features: https://www.meteor.com/try/7. Why not just use that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres a link to the open issue: https://github.com/meteor/windows-preview/issues/161

Also: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4155

Until its released, a workaround would be to fire up a Linux or iOS virtual machine and test from there.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible since 1.3 beta 11:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6050